# Convert all xml files in a directory to single or multiple csv files

Tags: xml, csv, directory

I have thousands of .xml files in a directory. I am not comfortable using xml and need to convert them to .csv files. It can be either one csv file for all the files or one for each, I prefer the latter. I do not know VBA either. How can I do this using a bash script or using some open source program? I did find many websites which convert one xml file to one csv file, but I need to do this for each and every one... I know MATLAB so a script in MATLAB would be great

Answer (score 0):

I made you a quick example using C#

```
    public class YourObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "your folder path";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourObject[]));
                    var data = (YourObject[])serializer.Deserialize(fs);
                    var list = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        var ss = new List<string>();
                        ss.Add(item.Name + ',' + item.Number);
                        list.Add(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, ss));
                    }
                    File.WriteAllLines("D:\\csvFile.csv", list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need to modify the class "YourObject" to represent your XML file structure.